# Let us continue this discussion in chat using redundant @name

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, chat, notifications

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176061/problem-with-a-moving-rotating-map/7176215#7176215) to a question, Danpe has moved the discussion to chat (automatically I assume).
Although I'm the OP of the answer, and the only other commenter, the automatic message,  "@GeorgeDuckett let us continue this discussion in chat", still uses "@GeorgeDuckett."

I think that "@name" should be removed where the notification would get sent anyway, in keeping with the automatic un-needed "@name" removal changes.

Comment: Ah, you mean the "@GeorgeDuckett let us continue this discussion in chat" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think that is valid - fixing for the next build